I have objects without UVs that I have created from modifiers and they do not appear
I created an object by using the Skin modifier from an SVG file. When I try to edit the UVs and select the entire object, the UVs do not appear.
Here is a screenshot of how I created the object with the Skin modifier.

Here you can see that the UVs of the object do not appear:

My question is, how do I create the UVs or how do I show them in the UV editing section?

(3D viewport, Edit mode,)   U  >  Smart UV Project.

Hola y bienvenido. El idioma inglés es obligatorio en el sitio. Si no te sientes cómodo con el idioma, usa el traductor de google. (English) hello and welcome. English is mandatory for the site. If you don't feel comfortable, try to use Google translate

Sorry. The next time I made the question in english

Hay que ver en el Object Data panel al derecho (es el con el triangulo verde), bajo del seccion UV Maps a ver si hay una UVMap. Si el mesh no lleva un UVMap hay que hacerlo usted mismo. Aqui esta un video explicando la manera

Your problem it is most likely because you are using a skin modifier but the modifier is not applied and you only have vertices and edges. Apply the skin modifier, then select your object and press U > UV unwrap
